# How can I create a smart pointer that locks and unlocks a mutex?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex, smart-pointers, raii

I have a threaded class from which I would like to occasionally acquire a pointer an instance variable. I would like this access to be guarded by a mutex so that the thread is blocked from accessing this resource until the client is finished with its pointer.

My initial approach to this is to return a pair of objects: one a pointer to the resource and one a shared_ptr to a lock object on the mutex. This shared_ptr holds the only reference to the lock object so the mutex should be unlocked when it goes out of scope. Something like this:

```
void A::getResource()
{
    Lock* lock = new Lock(&mMutex);
    return pair<Resource*, shared_ptr<Lock> >(
        &mResource, 
        shared_ptr<Lock>(lock));
}
```

This solution is less than ideal because it requires the client to hold onto the entire pair of objects. Behaviour like this breaks the thread safety:

```
Resource* r = a.getResource().first;
```

In addition, my own implementation of this is deadlocking and I'm having difficulty determining why, so there may be other things wrong with it.

What I would like to have is a shared_ptr that contains the lock as an instance variable, binding it with the means to access the resource. This seems like something that should have an established design pattern but having done some research I'm surprised to find it quite hard to come across.

My questions are:

- Is there a common implementation of this pattern?
- Are there issues with putting a mutex inside a shared_ptr that I'm overlooking that prevent this pattern from being widespread?
- Is there a good reason not to implement my own shared_ptr class to implement this pattern?

(NB I'm working on a codebase that uses Qt but unfortunately cannot use boost in this case. However, answers involving boost are still of general interest.)

Comment: Both answers from riv and Jonanthan Wakely are interesting and worth following. I'm going with Riz just because it's nice to have some complete collaboratively edited code in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any standard implementations, but since I like re-implementing stuff for no reason, here's a version that should work (assuming you don't want to be able to copy such pointers):

```
template<class T>
class locking_ptr
{
public:
  locking_ptr(T* ptr, mutex* lock)
    : m_ptr(ptr)
    , m_mutex(lock)
  {
    m_mutex->lock();
  }
  ~locking_ptr()
  {
    if (m_mutex)
      m_mutex->unlock();
  }
  locking_ptr(locking_ptr<T>&& ptr)
    : m_ptr(ptr.m_ptr)
    , m_mutex(ptr.m_mutex)
  {
    ptr.m_ptr = nullptr;
    ptr.m_mutex = nullptr;
  }

  T* operator ->()
  {
    return m_ptr;
  }
  T const* operator ->() const
  {
    return m_ptr;
  }
private:
  // disallow copy/assignment
  locking_ptr(locking_ptr<T> const& ptr)
  {
  }
  locking_ptr& operator = (locking_ptr<T> const& ptr)
  {
    return *this;
  }
  T* m_ptr;
  mutex* m_mutex; // whatever implementation you use
};
```

Comment: +1 this should do it - maybe disable assignment and add a move constructor?

Comment: Sure, you could disable assignment by moving the `operator =` to private section, but it should be safe as long as mutexes support nested locks. Added move constructor.

Comment: Fixed a couple typos; you could disable assignment with `= delete` keyword, but it is not supported by my Visual Studio.

Comment: Why are you you assigning `m_mutex = nullptr` in your copy constructor? You don't do any sanity checking in your destructor so you will end up calling `unlock()` on a null pointer.

Comment: Even in light of the danger of a possible off-topic discussion I don't really want to spark, but *"I generally avoid using std libraries"* - Ouch!

Comment: Oops I copied the wrong code... And regarding standard libraries, not sure why I mentioned that, I just like having my own non-template-heavy versions in my personal code.

Comment: Why have you implemented the copy constructor and copy assignment operator? Either make them private and **unimplemented**, or stop living in 1998 and define them as deleted.

Comment: Good point about unimplemented; however, `= delete` is not supported in VC10/11.

Answer (score 6):

You're describing a variation of the [EXECUTE AROUND POINTER](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Execute-Around_Pointer) pattern, described by Kevlin Henney in [Executing Around Sequences](http://hillside.net/europlop/HillsideEurope/Papers/ExecutingAroundSequences.pdf).

I have a prototype implementation at [`exec_around.h`](https://gitorious.org/redistd/redistd/?p=redistd:redistd.git;a=blob;f=include/redi/exec_around.h;hb=HEAD) but I can't guarantee it works correctly in all cases as it's a work in progress.  It includes a function `mutex_around` which creates an object and wraps it in a smart pointer that locks and unlocks a mutex when accessed.

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach here. Far less flexible and less generic, but also far simpler. While it still seems to fit your exact scenario.

`shared_ptr` (both [standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [Boost](https://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#shared_ptr)) offers means to construct it while providing another `shared_ptr` instance which will be used for usage counter and some arbitrary pointer that will not be managed at all. On [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/) it is the 8th form ([the aliasing constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)).

Now, normally, this form is used for conversions - like providing a `shared_ptr` to base class object from derived class object. They share ownership and usage counter but (in general) have two different pointer values of different types. This form is also used to provide a `shared_ptr` to a member value based on `shared_ptr` to object that it is a member of.

Here we can "abuse" the form to provide lock guard. Do it like this:

```
auto A::getResource()
{
    auto counter = std::make_shared<Lock>(&mMutex);
    std::shared_ptr<Resource> result{ counter, &mResource };
    return result;
}
```

The returned `shared_ptr` points to `mResource` and keeps `mMutex` locked for as long as it is used by anyone.

The problem with this solution is that it is now your responsibility to ensure that the `mResource` remains valid (in particular - it doesn't get destroyed) for that long as well. If locking `mMutex` is enough for that, then you are fine.

Otherwise, above solution must be adjusted to your particular needs. For example, you might want to have the `counter` a simple `struct` that keeps both the `Lock` and another `shared_ptr` to the `A` object owning the `mResource`.

Comment: If using `std::mutex`, what type should `Lock` be?

Comment: @Androvich, `std::lock_guard` as in your answer seems fine. You could use also `std::unique_lock` or any other implementation of the concept. However, for the presented need `std::lock_guard` is enough while it is also the simplest.

Comment: Yeah, it's working perfectly. Also, in your answer, shouldn't it be `std::make_shared<Lock>(mMutex)` instead of `std::make_shared<Lock>(&mMutex)`?

Comment: @Androvich, I don't think so. `Lock` will be a different type than `mMutex`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Adam Badura's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50165107/1658105), for a more general case using `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`, this worked for me:

```cpp
auto A::getResource()
{
    auto counter = std::make_shared<std::lock_guard<std::mutex>>(mMutex);
    std::shared_ptr<Resource> ptr{ counter, &mResource} ;
    return ptr;
}
```

where the lifetimes of `std::mutex mMutex` and `Resource mResource` are  managed by some class `A`.