# can I explicitly specialize std:shared_ptr::operator ->

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, shared-ptr

my first time asking a question, so fingers crossed.

I would like to provide a specialization of shared_ptr::operator-> 
The following wont compile on gcc 4.8.3

```
template<> 
widget* std::shared_ptr<widget>::operator->() const 
{ 
    return nullptr; 
}
```

I get the following compile error
error: no member function ‘operator->’ declared in ‘std::shared_ptr’

I've tried a few variations on how to specialize this and I keep getting the same error. e.g wrapping it up in a namespace std scope, also tried trailing reutrn types, making it noexcept etc etc

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Ah, no probs, I am trying to write some pre and post conditions using smart pointers. I can get them working easily enough using a hand written smart pointer that I wrote myself, but wanted to see if I could use some of the prebuilts ones, e.g. STL or boost.

Comment: Maybe have a look on this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876325/how-can-i-create-a-smart-pointer-that-locks-and-unlocks-a-mutex

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you are talking about a partial specialization. a full specialization can be standalone

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki  - That's what I thought, I;ve used explicit specialization countless times on member function of class templates, just never tired it with ones in the STL. Is there some template wizardry going on behind the scenes that prevents this from being done ?

Comment: @PMcK perhaps `shared_ptr` inherits `operator->` from its (hidden) base class, [like here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr.h#L93)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot specialize member functions from types within `std`.  Doing so makes your program ill-formed (and I believe no diagnostic is required).  Even if it "works" it is illegal.

You can specialize the entire type for a user-supplied type, but that basically involves rewriting `std::shared_ptr` from scratch.